# Unknown errors and warnings while implementing GCM client side

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, logcat

I'm trying to implement GCM client example found at [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart)
 but am not able to recelve notifications in my **MyGcmListenerService.java**

when i go through logs generated at my android studio logcat, i find this warnings and error messages

**Warnings**

```
10-07 15:22:47.160  29844-29844/com.me.myapp W/asset﹕ AssetManager-->
addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
10-07 15:22:47.352  29844-29844/com.me.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve
virtual method 247: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)
Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;

10-07 15:22:47.352  29844-29844/com.me.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve
 instance field 18

10-07 15:22:47.359  29844-29844/com.me.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve 
virtual method 1507: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getApplicationRestrictions
 (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
```

**Errors**

```
10-07 15:03:37.070  10177-10177/com.me.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 
'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common
.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzah

10-07 15:03:37.156  10177-10177/com.me.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 
'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.
GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb

10-07 15:03:38.117  10177-10197/com.me.myapp E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with
 status: 10

10-07 15:03:38.132  10177-10197/com.me.myapp E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible.
 App measurement disabled

10-07 15:07:11.320  10306-10306/com.me.myapp E/SensorManager﹕ thread start

10-07 15:07:17.164  10306-10703/com.me.myapp E/API_TASK﹕ Read timed out
```

**Question**

- how can i solve some or all or of this errors and warnings?
- Do they have to do with my failure to receive notifications from GCM server ?

Comment: Have you included GooglePlayService in application?

Comment: @vishalk       yes! i have. exactly as shown in the gitlab example

Comment: Hey did you solve this? I need a solution to this.

Comment: @KevinKaburu are you getting the same errors in your logcat?

Comment: this what am getting::    11-18 21:27:55.205 14469-14469/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb

Comment: @KevinKaburu    what is your target sdk? because `android.app.AppOpsManager` class  is found in sdk 19 and above

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mbavin.virtual"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

Comment: @gikarasojokinene AM good now. Seems like that was not the problem. It was my stupid mistike, I had not added the service to Manifest file

Comment: could you fix also i have same errors

Comment: @Clara_57S  coundn't understand your question. what problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Just like yours, getGoogleAppId failed with
 status: 10 and E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible.
 App measurement disabled

Comment: @Clara_57S have you tried the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated errors and problems have nothing to do with receiving gcm notifications. for my case. gcmid received from gcm connection server wasn't being saved at datastore. the entity responsible for saving it was badly implemented thus i coundn't receive messages or notifications from GCM Connection servers.

- Make sure gcmId received from connection servers is well saved in your app server.(i use objectify to achieve this)
- Also make use of `Logger` class at your backend module in order to track your implementation by printing out logs(messages) at important stages. e.g when you receive gcmid (you can implement this at the frontend thus use `Log.d()` method), if gcmid have been saved to your app server( here you use entities to do that and its here where you use `Logger class` **because this takes place at backend module**).

**Still stucked? comment below to ask for help**