# Google Map crashes on Android when listener calls method

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My Google maps activity is crashing when I call a method that I created in the onCameraChange listener.

The map works fine until I actually touch the map and the listener is called:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
            VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
            double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
            double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
            double right = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;
            double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;

            zoomFix(position);
            checkXYAxis(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    });
```

If I comment out the method 'checkXYAxis' it works fine.  Method:

```
public void checkXYAxis(double left, double top, double right, double bottom) {
    //X
    if (left < -87.896567) {
        left = -87.896567;
    }
    else if (right > -87.874628) {
        right = -87.874628;
    }
    //Y
    if (top > 43.178949) {
        top = 43.169292;
    }
    else if (bottom < 43.169292) {
        bottom = 43.169292;
    }

    //update camera position
    LatLng southwest = new LatLng(bottom, left);
    LatLng northeast = new LatLng(top, right);
    LatLngBounds newBounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, 0);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}
```

Somewhere in that method it is causing a crash to happen.

Here is the error output:

```
12-23 23:46:21.903 16841-16841/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-23 23:46:21.973 16841-16841/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap W/ActivityThread: Application com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap can be debugged on port 8100...
12-23 23:46:22.033 16841-16862/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
12-23 23:46:22.043 16841-16862/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
12-23 23:46:22.043 16841-16862/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
12-23 23:46:22.153 16841-16864/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-23 23:46:22.153 16841-16841/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-23 23:46:22.203 16841-16864/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
                                                                                      Build Date: 04/20/15 Mon
                                                                                      Local Branch: 
                                                                                      Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.1.3_rb1.11
                                                                                      Local Patches: NONE
                                                                                      Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017 + 26a3cba + 6f69ea6 + 8bc2bc8 + 649fcde + a52cccf + dbf281f +  NOTHING
12-23 23:46:22.203 16841-16864/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-23 23:46:22.223 16841-16864/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-23 23:46:22.313 16841-16841/com.lightningboltstudios.audubontrailmap I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@24d7d29d time:28513116
```

Comment: Are there other error logs that can be provided when `onCameraChanged` is called? Based on the current logs, getGoogleAppId error seems to be related to an apk key issue (as suggested in [this SO issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992387/unknown-errors-and-warnings-while-implementing-gcm-client-side)). csixty suggests you make sure that permissions are inserted and spelled correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however as I stated above: "If I comment out the method 'checkXYAxis' it works fine" - which means the map is still being rendered using the google APK key and is fine.

Comment: I've tried using an await, set a flag to keep it from running the code, nothing seems to work.. it seems to be recursively calling the listener before the map is done moving as defined in the API.